# Show that if $p$ is a prime number then there exists $n$ such that $2^n(p+1) - 1$ is not a prime number.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

Show that if $p$ is a prime number then there exists $n$ natural number such that $2^n(p+1) - 1$ is not a prime number.

I tried to prove by contradiction, by assuming that $a_n = 2^n(p+1) - 1$ is an increasing sequence of prime numbers.
The only interesting relations I obtained regarding this sequence are the following :
$$ a_{n + 1} - a_n = (p+1)2^n $$
$$ a_n^2 = (p+1) (a_{2n} + 1) - a_{n + 1}$$
Thus $p + 1$ divides both $a_{n + 1} - a_n$ and $a_{n + 1} + a_n^2$ and thus $p + 1$ divides $a_n^2 + a_n$.

But I am not sure how to continue from here. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hint: what happens when $n=p-1$?

Comment: Thank you a lot! I see the solution now.

Answer (score 1):

Use Mod $p$. The little fermat theorem implies that $2^{p-1}=1$ $mod$ $p$ implies that $2^{p-1}(p+1)-1=0$  $mod$ $p$.